# How to set to this only uppercase letters? Random choice

Tags: python

```
code = ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(6))
```

How to set to this only uppercase letters and add "RF" before?

RF(6 random uppercase letter)

Example:

```
RFQXCZLN
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) instead:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> 'RF' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in xrange(6))
'RFOCJTGN'
```

Using `random.choice()` will result in a random string that *can* have repeating characters:

```
>>> 'RF' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in xrange(6))
'RFBYBXHM'
```

Note the two `B` characters. If you do not want characters to repeat, then uses [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) instead:

```
>>> 'RF' + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 6))
'RFEVKZHD'
```

and the 6 random characters are guaranteed not to contain repeats.

Comment: the full line would be:
`code = "RF" + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in xrange(6))`

Answer (score 2):

Use [random.sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) and [string.ascii_uppercase](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase)

```
>>> "RF" + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 6))
'RFBGHZMW'
```

Comment: `random.sample()` would preclude any repetition of characters. That must be an explicit choice!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def getCode(length = 10, char = string.ascii_uppercase):
       return ''.join(random.choice( char) for x in range(length))

>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> getCode(6)
'ADKCGW'
```

If your want other chars and length

```
>>> getCode(5, "mychars")
'ahssh'
```

A run on [codepade](http://codepad.org/hGwXI98O)

**EDIT** 
to add "RE" in front of random chars

```
>>> "RE" + getCode(6)
REIUXWUE
```